# Android Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm using Eclipse. I am getting this error in my custom style.xml:

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/
>    Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar'.

In Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I also made sure that project.properties file has target=android-17 (Android 4.2.2) and I just cleaned and built my project, but the error persists

My custom style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <resources>
      <style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
      <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
      <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
      <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
      <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
      <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
      <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/ad_btn_check_holo_light</item>
      <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/ad_btn_radio_holo_light</item>
  </style>

<!-- style the list navigation -->
<style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@color/vermelho</item>
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/orange</item>
<item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/seletor2</item>
    </style>

<!-- style for the tabs -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
 </style>

  <!-- style the overflow menu -->
 <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
 <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/ad_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item> 
 </style>

 <!-- style the items within the overflow menu -->
 <style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
 <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/seletor2</item>
 </style>

 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarbackground</item>
 </style>
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:style/
>   Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar'.

**Don't**

```
 parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"
```

**Do**

```
 parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild** Your App .

Comment: Yes, it worked! But nothing changed. It continues with the default styling in list navigation mode has a blue colour scheme

Comment: you should customize on it

Comment: I know, I did it Now another Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no resource as

`parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar"`

instead use this

```
parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
```

Comment: Another Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView'.